# Is there a function or method in vue.js just like ng-init in angularjs ？

Tags: vue.js

I want to initialize the data in *.vue, but the method of 'created' just run once, so is there a method run anytime just like the directive 'ng-init' in angulajs?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you explain what exactly `ng-init` does, that `created` does not?

Comment: @nils 'ng-init' call a function every time when you enter a page, but 'created' just call once in lifecycle,

Comment: Enter a page, as in navigating with a router (e.g. `vue-router`)?

Comment: Yes,you can think so!

Comment: @nils Yes,you can think so!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In vue-router for vue 1, there used to be an `activate` hook which allowed you to do that.

As far as I can see, in vue 2 it is only slightly more complicated. Let's say you have an `init` method to initialize your state.

[The `$route` object changes when you navigate, so you can `watch` it and reinitialize your data, every time the component exists.](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/data-fetching.html#fetching-after-navigation)

```
  created () {
    // fetch the data when the view is created and the data is
    // already being observed
    this.init()
  },
  watch: {
    // call again the method if the route changes
    '$route': 'init'
  },
```